# Retrofit response returning null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

I want to fetch live data from coinbase api. I'm using Retrofit to make API call I got a null response when i tried returning displaying the data

the json response from the api
**JSON**

```html
{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"9510.915"}}
```

The retrofit class for the returned data
**RETROFIT**

```html
 myC2C = RetrofitClient.getInstance("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/").create(IMyC2C.class);
       
 Call<DataList> call = myC2C.getPrice("USD");

  call.enqueue(new Callback<DataList>() {
            @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<DataList> call, Response<DataList> response) {

                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    usd_price.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                
                 Log.d("resedatasync", new Gson().toJson(response.body().getDatas()));
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataList> call, Throwable t) {
                usd_price.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
```

The endpoint that calls get methods and parse the type of currency
**ENDPOINT**

```html
@GET("spot")
    Call<DataList> getPrice(@Query("currency") String currency);
```

the java model class here
**JAVA CLASS

```css
import java.util.List;

public class DataList {
    private Datas Datas;

    public Datas getDatas() {
        return Datas;
    }

    public void setDatas(Datas datas) {
        this.Datas = datas;
    }
}
```

```html
package com.example.c2c.Model;

public class Datas {

    private String base;
    private String currency;
    private float amount;

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

**

Comment: You need to add a converter

Comment: public class RetrofitClient {
        private static Retrofit instance;

        public static Retrofit getInstance(String BaseUrl){
            if (instance == null){
                instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return instance;
        }

}

Comment: I think your sever response is not in json format.